itemStyle does not work in sunburst when there is visual Map but it works in tree map with the visual map. what could be the issue?
Link to Minimal Reproduction
Reproduction link - TreeMap
Reproduction link - Sunburst
Steps to Reproduce

Add continuous visual map to the sunburst.
One data point to havevalue zero, and itemstyle which has color in it, label color white.
Label color shows up in both Treemap and sunburst.
In treemap, it works as expected i.e., it shows the tile in gray. When you change the type to Sunburst, tile is in color green instead of gray.

Treemap with Visual Map

Sunburst with Visual Map

Sunburst without Visual Map

Current Behavior
In treemap, When the value is '0', tile shows up in gray color as itemstyle with color is added but in sunburst, tile is in green color, despite having the itemstyle.
Expected Behavior
In Sunburst, tile color has to be in gray color

If values, that are outside of the specified min and max for the visualMap, should have a different color, you can use the outOfRange property (which seems to not quite work if the range equals min / max). A workaround is to specify slightly different values for range and min / max.
Example:
var data = [
  {
    name: 'Grandpa',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Cousin Jack',
        value: 2
      },
      {
        name: 'Cousin Mary',
        value: 5
      },
      {
        name: 'Cousin Ben',
        value: 4
      },

      {
        name: 'Me',
        value: 5
      },
      {
        name: 'Brother Peter',
        value: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Nancy',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Cousin Betty',
        value: 1
      },
      {
        name: 'Cousin Jenny',
        value: 8
      }
    ]
  }
];

option = {
  series: {
    type: 'sunburst',
    data: data
  },
  visualMap: [
    {
      type: 'continuous',
      min: 1.999999999,
      max: 10.00000001,
      range: [2, 10],
      inRange: {
        color: ['green', 'yellow', 'red']
      },
      outOfRange: {
        color: 'grey'
      }
    }
  ]
};


